# import npm modules asynchronously in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

I am using parcel as a bundler in React.js project.

How to **load npm modules asynchronously** in **react.js**?

There is only one page that uses one specific npm module so I didn't need to load it at first loading.

By avoiding this, I would like to reduce the **bundle size**.

Could you let me the proper way to do this?

========================

And also, if I understood anything wrongly about the **bundle size optimization** and **lazy loading**, please let me know.

Comment: https://parceljs.org/code_splitting.html

Comment: @Eggy Thank you for your too quick hints ;) Can we use this parcel code splitting feature to import node modules? And if so, is it not included at the first loading? Furthermore, FCM is gonna be reduced if we load all npm modules like this? ( which is crazy if so )

Comment: See [Code splitting in react](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_Ak1pn-n4k)

Answer (score 1):

By using [Dynamic Import](https://parceljs.org/code_splitting.html#using-dynamic-imports) you may import the package when you really need the package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic import inside an `useEffect` hook like:

```
const Page = (props) => {
    useEffect(
        () => {
            const [momentjsPromise, cancel] = makeCancelable(import("moment"));

            momentjsPromise.then((momentjs) => {
                // handle states here
            });

            return () => {
                cancel?.();
            };
        },
        [
            /* don't forget the dependencies */
        ],
    );
};
```

Comment: what is makeCancelable?

Comment: [makeCancelable](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5465#issuecomment-157888325).  This is slightly different from what I use. My version returns an array and this return an object but it is essentially the same. See [this post](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) to know why to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic imports.

Let's say you want to import `my-module`:

```
const Component = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    import('my-module').then(mod => {
      // my-module is ready
      console.log(mod);
    }); 
  }, []); 
   
  return <div>my app</div>
}
```

Another way is to [code-splitt](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) `Component` itself:

```
// ./Component.js
import myModule from 'my-module';

export default () => <div>my app</div>


// ./App.js
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./Component'));

const App = () => (
  <Suspense>
    <OtherComponent />
  <Suspense>
);
```

`my-module` will be splitted along with Component.

These two patterns should work with any bundler, but it will work client side only.